# How to make Anaconda pip as the default pip

Tags: python, python3, pip, anaconda

My Python 3 `pip` is messing up. Apparently I have a non-conda pip as the default pip but conda python is my default python (as below), which is messing up with package installations:

```
>which -a pip
/home/<user>/.local/bin/pip   
/home/<user>/.conda/envs/newenv/bin/pip
/usr/bin/pip

>which -a python
/home/<user>/.conda/envs/newenv/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

Looks like to address this issue, instead of just calling `pip install <package>`, I should use `python -m pip install <package>`.

Now the question is, is there any ways to make conda pip the default pip? So to avoid writing `python -m pip install` and directly use pip to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple resetting worked for me:

```
# Deactivate from your conda env (if  you are on base you will exit, if not base do it again to exit)
conda deactivate
conda activate


# check your pip and python
which -a pip
which -a python
```

reference to the issue thread: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1429